# Getting exception : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;) while using data frames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am receiving "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)" error while using dataframes in scala app and running it using spark. However if I work using only RDD's and not dataframes, no such error comes up with same pom and settings. Also while going through other posts with same error, it is mentioned that scala version has to be 2.10 as spark is not compatible with 2.11 scala, and i am using 2.10 scala version with 2.0.0 spark.

```
Below is the snip from pom:



<properties>
      <spark-assembly>/usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly.jar</spark-assembly>
      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      <hadoop.version>2.7.1</hadoop.version>
      <hbase.version>1.1.1</hbase.version>
      <scala.version>2.10.5</scala.version>
      <scala.tools.version>2.10</scala.tools.version>
      <spark.version>2.0.0</spark.version>
      <phoenix.version>4.7.0-HBase-1.1</phoenix.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
          <version>${scala.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
          <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
          <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
          <version>${hbase.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
          <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
          <version>${hbase.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Error:

```
16/10/19 02:57:26 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
        at com.abc.xyz.Compare$.main(Compare.scala:64)
        at com.abc.xyz.Compare.main(Compare.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
16/10/19 02:57:26 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;)
16/10/19 02:57:26 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 9):

Change scala version

`<scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version`>

```
<scala.tools.version>2.11</scala.tools.version>
```

and add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>${scala.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: after adding the above in pom.xml, have you cleaned the project?

Comment: Just for my doubt, i read it everywhere that scala 2.10 should be used, is that applicable toh just spark 1.6? and 2.11 should be used with spark 2.0? Also, what is the use of scala reflect?

Comment: For the Scala API, Spark 2.0.0 uses Scala 2.11
check this one https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/

Comment: What about scala-reflect?

Comment: Its a compiler for scala. If you want to know more check scala doc http://docs.scala-lang.org

Comment: what do you mean by cleaning the project in spark?  @user1534615

Comment: cleaning the project means doing mvn clean

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this error and this is purely a version issue.

Your scala version is not compatible or may be you are using the correct version but the intellij  libraries has the old version.

Quick fix :

I as using spark 2.2.0 and scala 2.10.4 , which I then changed to scala version 2.11.8.After that do the below:

1) right click on intellij module 
2) open module-settings.
3) go to libraries and clear all of them 
4) Rebuild

Doing above for me issue is resolved.